# How to solve this seemingly simple system of algebraic equations?

Tags: equation-solving, complex

I mean
$$ \text{z1}+\text{z2}+\text{z3}+\text{z4}=0\land | \text{z1}| =| \text{z2}| \land | \text{z3}| =| \text{z2}| 
\land | \text{z3}| =| \text{z4}|$$
in $\text{z1},\text{z2},\text{z3},\text{z4}$ over the complexes.

Here are my unsuccessful trials in 13.2 on Windows 10.

(i)

```
Solve[z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 == 0 && Abs[z1] == Abs[z2] && Abs[z3] == Abs[z2] && Abs[z3] == Abs[z4], 
{z1, z2, z3,z4}, Complexes]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found;
> use Reduce for complete solution information.
>
> Solve::svars: Equations may not give solutions for all "solve" variables.
>
> `{{z2->z1,z3->-z1,z4->-z1},{z2->-z1,z3->z1,z4->-z1},{z2->-z1,z3->-z1,z4->z1},{z1->0,z2->0,z3->0,z4->0}}`

Most  of the solutions are lost.

(ii)
The command

```
Reduce[z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 == 0 && Abs[z1] == Abs[z2] && Abs[z3] == Abs[z2] && 
Abs[z3] == Abs[z4], {z1, z2, z3, z4}, Complexes]
```

almost crashes my comp: "Kernel connection is lost".

(iii)

With the additional constraint `Abs[z1]==1`,

```
Solve[z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 == 0 && Abs[z1] == Abs[z2] && Abs[z3] == Abs[z2] && 
Abs[z3] == Abs[z4] && Abs[z1] == 1, {z1, z2, z3, z4}, Complexes]
```

> Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found;
> use Reduce for complete solution information.

> `{{z1 -> 1, z2 -> 1, z3 -> -1, z4 -> -1}, {z1 -> 1, z2 -> -1, z3 -> 1,  z4 -> -1}, {z1 -> -1, z2 -> 1, z3 -> 1, z4 -> -1}, {z1 -> 1,  z2 -> -1, z3 -> -1, z4 -> 1}, {z1 -> -1, z2 -> 1, z3 -> -1,  z4 -> 1}, {z1 -> -1, z2 -> -1, z3 -> 1, z4 -> 1}}`

Most  of the solutions are lost.

(iv)

```
Reduce[z1 + z2 + z3 + z4 == 0 && Abs[z1] == Abs[z2] &&  Abs[z3] == Abs[z2] &&
Abs[z3] == Abs[z4] && Abs[z1] == 1, {z1, z2, z3, z4}, Complexes]
```

is running without any response on my comp for hours. The resources of
my comp are not exhausted. Likely an infinite loop is formed.

(v) The switching to the reals by

```
Reduce[x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 == 0 && y1 + y2 + y3 + y4 == 0 && 
x1^2 + y1^2 == x2^2 + y2^2 && x3^2 + y3^2 == x2^2 + y2^2 && 
x3^2 + y3^2 == x4^2 + y4^2 && x1^2 + y1^2 == 1, {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1,y2, y3, y4},Reals]
```

does not help. The command is running without any response on my comp for hours. The resources of
my comp are not exhausted. Likely an infinite loop is created.

Comment: If the absolute values of all the complexes are the same, it should help to reformulate the problem as `z1 = r Exp[I phi1]` etc. and impose that `r >= 0`.

Comment: As I know it, the geometric interpretation of the solutions is the following: `z1, z2, z3,  z4` are vertices of a rectangle (maybe, a degenerate one) in the complex plane centered at the origin

Comment: @SjoerdSmit, you can go even further by taking `r==1`

Comment: This is a 2-parameter family if we restrict length to be 1.

Comment: The geometric interpretation is more general: `z1,z2,z3,z4` form a rhombus!

Answer (score 2):

By taking `z1==1`, you can find a solution set that you can scale by any complex constant.

Decomposing into real and imaginary components I have

```
eqn = 1 + c1 + c2 + c3 == 0 && s1 + s2 + s3 == 0 && c1^2 + s1^2 == c2^2 + s2^2 == c3^2 + s3^2 == 1;
```

This can be solved easily using

```
Reduce[eqn, Reals]
```

Alternatively, you find a few interesting values, e.g.

```
FindInstance[1 + c1 + c2 + c3 == 0 && s1 + s2 + s3 == 0 && 
c1^2 + s1^2 == c2^2 + s2^2 == c3^2 + s3^2 == 1, {c1, c2, c3, s1, s2, s3}, Reals, 8]
```

Comment: Thank you.  I find this approach advanced.  Sum spots on the Sun.  (i) "By taking z1==1, you can find a solution set that you can scale by any complex constant" should be elaborated.

Comment: (ii)  Your result is `a=((c3 == 0 && ((c2 == 
          0 && ((s2 == 1 && 1 + s3 == 0) || (1 + s2 == 0 && 
             s3 == 1))) || (1 + c2 == 0 && 
         s2 == 0 && (s3 == 1 || 1 + s3 == 0)))) || (s3 == 
      0 && ((1 + c3 == 
          0 && ((c2 == 0 && (1 + s2 == 0 || s2 == 1)) || (s2 == 
              0 && (c2 == 1 || 1 + c2 == 0)) || ((-1 < s2 < 0 || 
               0 < s2 < 1) && (Sqrt[1 - s2^2] == c2 || 
               c2 + Sqrt[1 - s2^2] == 0)))) ||`

Comment: `(1 + c2 == 0 && 
         c3 == 1 && s2 == 0))) || ((-1 < s3 < 0 || 
       0 < s3 < 
        1) && ((s2 == 0 && 
         c2 + Sqrt[c3^2 + s3^2] == 
          0 && (Sqrt[1 - s3^2] == c3 || 
           c3 + Sqrt[1 - s3^2] == 0)) || (s2 + s3 == 
          0 && ((c3 + Sqrt[1 - s3^2] == 0 && 
             Sqrt[c3^2 - s2^2 + s3^2] == c2) || (Sqrt[1 - s3^2] == 
              c3 && c2 + Sqrt[c3^2 - s2^2 + s3^2] == 0)))))) && 
 s1 + s2 + s3 == 0 && 1 + c1 + c2 + c3 == 0` . This  description leaves much to be desired. For example `a /. {c3 -> 1/2, s1 -> 1/4, s3 -> -1/4}` results in `False`.

Comment: (iii) I repeat "As I know it, the geometric interpretation of the solutions is the following: `z1, z2, z3,  z4` are  the vertices of a rectangle (maybe, a degenerate one) in the complex plane centered at the origin".